# How to remove user from Attendee list in .ics?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am using .ics file to send calendar invite to google users from my app, when a user is removed from the attendees in my app,

- I am resending the .ics with updated attendees list to attendees who are still in the meeting.
- send the removed attendees new .ics with cancel event.

however, the removed attendees are still showing in the event for other users.

how do I remove attendees from event using ICS?

first .ics:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:MyDemoApp
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:useremovetest1jdfshsdpfh
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20191014T085551Z
DTSTAMP:20191014T085551Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20191014T085551Z
DTSTART:20191014T112347Z
DTEND:20191014T113547Z
SUMMARY:user remove test - 2
LOCATION:@my-dev-env
DESCRIPTION:some dummy desc 
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=
 true:mailto:user1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=
 true:mailto:user2@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=
 true:mailto:user3@gmail.com
ORGANIZER;CN=Invitation - user remove test - 2:user1@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

.ics when a attendee is removed:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:MyDemoApp
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:useremovetest1jdfshsdpfh
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20191014T085422Z
DTSTAMP:20191014T085422Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20191014T085422Z
DTSTART:20191014T112347Z
DTEND:20191014T113547Z
SUMMARY:user remove test - 2
LOCATION:@my-dev-env
DESCRIPTION:some dummy desc - update
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=true;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-AC
 TION:mailto:user1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=
 true:mailto:TION:mailto:user2@gmail.com
ORGANIZER;CN=Invitation - user remove test - 2:user1@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

user2@gmail.com still stays in the attendee list. however, title, desc etc are updating successfully.

Comment: Aside from not upgrading the sequence number and the timestamp issue, you seem to be doing exactly what [RFC446 section 4.2.10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5546#section-4.2.10) suggests.

Comment: @sahith Hi! I know it's been a while, but I am stuck on the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DTSTAMP and LAST-MODIFIED values are "backward" in the sense that the updated invite has an earlier timestamp than the original one.

First invite:

```
DTSTAMP:20191014T085551Z
```

Updated invite:

```
DTSTAMP:20191014T085422Z
```

As a consequence this second ics is likely to be ignored by clients as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-2.1.5

Comment: I do not think that the second ics is being ignored by clients, because the I was able to change desc & event title using the file.